# Info from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in javascript, and my problem is that I want to take info from php to javascript code.

```
    <? $info = "500", "5", "222"; ?>
<script>

    var names = $('info')</script>
```

Thank you, for your answers

Comment: <script>var names = '<?= json_encode($info');?>'; </script>

Comment: try this
<script>
    var name = '<?php echo "Doskins" ?>';

    alert(name);
    
</script>